# How are disabled passengers evacuated during emergency?

Tags: faa-regulations, passenger, emergency-procedures, evacuation

Basically the title. However, I would request if someone can throw some light on how FAA or the airlines train the crew to handle emergency evacuations with a disabled person on board. Are the ramps and slides accessible to persons with disabilities?

Comment: I strongly suspect that this depends on the type of handicap in question.

Comment: Toss them down the emergency chutes if they can't jump/slide themselves?

Comment: @dalearn why can't the crew hold them and jump together on the escape chute?

Answer (score 7):

You can find the full text of [the FAA's recommendations in this AC](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC120-32.pdf)

But the flight attendant is responsible for discussing with them whats best.

> **ASSISTING DISABLED PERSONS.** The handicapped person knows best . the
>   manner in wbch he can be assisted, and flight attendants should not
>   hesitate to discuss this with the individual. Keep in mind that
>   different disabilities have different needs, and injury can result if
>   a person with a disability is improperly assisted.

The AC goes on to describe most major scenarios and common instances.