How does a paraplegic jump off a slide in an emergency?
On a typical airliner, or any other airplane, what is the emergency procedure for a paraplegic (or other disabled people) to be able to get out of the airplane?
Obviously the flight attendants will need to assist anyone who is mobility impaired to the exits, but I'm looking for a specific example of the wording used to establish how this will be performed, and in what sequence.
Consider for example:

Someone (presumably a flight attendant) will need to exit first to be in a position to catch them and help them out of the way.
Moving the person from their seat to the exit may require several attendants depending on the person's weight, and doing so will block the aisle and impede able bodied passengers.

Does anybody have an example of specific airline procedures describing how such an evacuation is to be performed?

What are you looking for besides "the flight attendants help"?

He doesn't go first, because there would be nobody to catch him. And he doesn't go last, because there would be nobody to throw him.

Seriously though, there must be a procedure for this, anyone with cabin crew training please chime in!

@Jpe61 that's what I'm saying, as simple as it might be, there must be something written somewhere about this.

I am being serious.  Specific wording will likely vary a little by airline, but probably consist of a puffed up version of my first comment, i.e. "in the event of emergency evacuation, flight attendants shall assist those who are mobility impaired to the exits..."  So back to my question, are you looking for specific words like "place your hands under the armpits and lift upwards..."?  Again, not trying to be snarky, but just not sure what you are looking for in an answer here...

@MichaelHall yeah stuff like that, for example @ A.I. Breveleri's point was a good one, he/she can't be the first nor the last one.

Please take a look at my edit and let me know if you think it is an improvement.  I will delete my comments if you agree...

Actually, I think this is a dupe with a good answer already:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42947/how-are-disabled-passengers-evacuated-during-emergency?rq=1

@MichaelHall yeah, that was great, the pdf has a lot of info, it even talks about a blind person traveling with their dog., etc...
